# VCPKG, not a found command right after installing it?

Tags: c, vcpkg, bgi

I am trying to use `#include<graphics.h>` in visual studio code to display graphics in C. When I used graphics.h as a header the following error occurred,

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\natha\Desktop\My OS\src\impl\kernel\main.c).C/C++(1696)

cannot open source file "graphics.h"
```

So as the quick fix suggests it shows me how to install a library for this header with VCPKG (https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html). When I follow the steps by cloning the repository and running the bootstrap, I go to install the graphics package but the cmd says that 'vcpkg' is not a found command. I'm not sure why it says this or how to fix it.

Comment: `graphics.h` isn't within a vcpkg package as far as i know, but part of the Borland Toolchain. This seesm unrelated to vcpkg and make sure your include paths are correctly set

Answer (score 2):

Add the vcpkg.exe binary path to the PATH environment variable
or run vcpkg from the directory where you installed